# table undefined in pushing laravel app to heroku when discovering package

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Table undefined in pushing laravel app to heroku when discovering package.

Here is my code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use App\Year;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    $years = Year::pluck('name', 'id');
view()->share(compact('years'));


}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
}
```

---

Erroor : SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "years" does not exist
remote:          LINE 1: select "name", "id" from "years"

Comment: Have you migrated your database?

Comment: whats ur database postgress?

Comment: Yes i migrated and i use postgress